# How to call cxf webservice that takes multiple parameters through java?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have created some web services using apache cxf and I am trying to call these through my java code. But, since my services takes multiple parameters, I am not getting how to pass these parameters. For eg, my service is

```
helloWorld(String jsonString, String userName)
```

and my java code is:

```
 public String helloWorld(String jsonString, String userName)
{


URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/abc/helloWorld");


          HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          conn.setDoOutput(true);
          conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
          conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

          String input=jsonString;
          OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
          os.write(input.getBytes()); 

}
```

I am not getting how to pass username along with my jsonString..  ?

Comment: are those path parameters or query parameters ?

Comment: those are query parameters.

Comment: then give the parameters in url itself ! like http://localhost:8080/abc/helloWorld?userName=AppleBud

Comment: Is there any way I can pass it the way I am passing my json string? The reason is that I can't change my service method implementations

Comment: you don't have to change anything here but client code. Since username is query parameter it goes in the url not as a post body.

Comment: May be I am getting it wrong but, like I am processing my jsonString, similarly i want to send my userName. That's my basic question.